# How to write Unit test cases for template passed another template in Vue 3 with Vitest and test-utils

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vitest

I am trying to write the unit test case for a component which has this structure.

```
<template>
<someComponent :prop1="val" :prop2="val1">
     <template #target>
           <MySecondComponent :prop1="v1" :prop2="v2">
           </MySecondComponent>
    </template>
<someComponent>
</template>
```

I want to write unit test cases for MySecondComponent. How can i acheive this ?

Comment: What did you try? For *unit* test, you provide a test double for MySecondComponent and assert that it receives the props you expect